# phpmyadmin logic command to unpublish records in table stored before set period of time

Tags: mysql

I have date as DB column
Can someone advise on a command in phpmyadmin which will unpublish all records more than 6 month old

For Instance -
v_id : unique record value given to every record

Adddate : Date field - values stores as 2015-11-23 09:39:28 (Year-Month-Date Time)

v_status : 1 means published and 0 means unpublished

Table name xyz_used

What command can i run in my phpadmin so that it can unpublish i.e make V_id record status i.e. v_status as 0 having adddate as before 2015-05-31 in table xyz_used

Pls am not aware of command at all - hence asking question for help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all **phpmyadmin** is a tool or webapp to access mysql databases. you can say it is a client utility.

Second

To update a table you will need to write **Update Sql Query** where you can put the date and can set the status.

query would be like

```
Updaate <tbl> set v_status = 0 where datefield  < date_sub(now(), interval 6 month);
```